# HTML mail with embedded image using cid linkedresource in c#

Tags: c#, html, image, email, gmail

How can I properly send HTML email with embedded image using LinkedResources? My sample code is working and shows correctly images in Outlook (both desktop application and android app), and also in web Gmail but does not display image in Android Gmail app. What can I do to make it work?

Sample code in C#:

```
    LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(
        @"c:\path-to-file\logo.jpg",           //Path of file
        "image/jpg");                          
    logo.ContentId = "logo";                   //ID for reference

    //Actual HTML content of the body in an 'AlternateView' object.
    AlternateView vw = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
        "Hello, this is <b>HTML</b> mail with embedded image: <img src=\"cid:logo\" />",
        null,
        MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);              
    vw.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

    var msg = new MailMessage() { IsBodyHtml = true };
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(vw);

    var emailFrom = "from@email.xyz";
    var emailTo = "to@email.xyz";

    msg.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));

    msg.Subject = "HTML mail with image!";
    
    using (var client = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25))
        client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Have you checked the received HTML content? Is there any difference?

Comment: The image has to be a MIME Attachment.  See following for an example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: Maybe this will help you with the attachment part: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/